# Set number of values for a field in an entityform type based on a fixed value

Tags: forms, entities

I'm working with an entityform type that has a field with unlimited input values, so with the default button "Add another" I can add multple values for a field.

I'd like to fix this number of values, maybe with a get or post value, so I can preselect a specific number of values and then limit user to fill a specific number of fields.

Example: 
first select how many items to order --> user selects 4 items --> user must fill 4 values of the same field and user can't add more or less then 4 items.

Do you think it's possible with drupal modules?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searches I found a solution: https://www.drupal.org/node/2868353